# Do dynamic responses (PHP, Django, etc) set any sort "not static" variable in the response header?

Tags: php, html, django, browser-cache, server-side-includes

If I have some site on a server:

```
//hello.html
<html> hello </html>
```

Would all of the following be requested and/or cached individually:

`http://hello.html`, `http://hello.html?place=world`, `http://hello.html?foo=bar`

...even though they are the same result?

Is there some variable in the header that denotes the difference between a static (always the same) response to a request and one which has had some meddling (ie. PHP, templates)?

EDIT: if the site was (I don't know PHP):

```
<html><?php
   print "hello"+$_GET['place'];;
?></html>
```

the results would be different for the three urls:

`http://hello.html`, `http://hello.html?place=world`, `http://hello.html?foo=bar`

Is the response header also changed to express that for all three the page is not static (not cacheable)?

Comment: i know all the words you use, it's the order that they come in which makes no sense.

Comment: responce headers from this page"CF-RAY 
28325ee2933118f6-AKL
Cache-Control 
private, max-age=0
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Encoding 
gzip
Content-Length 
18629
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=utf-8
Date 
Sun, 13 Mar 2016 20:52:37 GMT
Server 
cloudflare-nginx
Vary 
Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options 
SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid 
4e8ce6bd-c9f2-4353-8d42-758a2d9004e6"

Comment: http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html

Comment: off the top of your head, would `Cache-Control public` be the response of the first example but not the second?  I'm also trying to figure it out from the link above.

Comment: There is no header to difference between a static or dynamic response. You can tell the browser to cache static files by sending the appropriate `Cache-Control` header and to not cache other (dynamic) files by sending the appropriate `Cache-Control` header (e.g. `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store`). But you or the webserver (based on config) has to send these headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based off of a comment by @CharlotteDunois.  If he adds an answer, I'll take this one down.

There is no implicit difference between the header of a dynamic vs static response.

There does exist a header setting called [`Cache-Control`](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html) which can tell a browser that something that does not look static actually is.

If doing I'm the one doing the web service, I can set the header to have `Cache-Control`, but I can not depend on other servers to always do the same.